Padding for SHAKE256
I have confusion regarding the padding for SHAKE256 that I am implementing.
Below are the snippets from FIPS 202
SHAKE256(M, d) = KECCAK[512] (M || 1111, d)

Algorithm 9: pad10*1(x, m)
Input:
positive integer x;
non-negative integer m.
Output:
string P such that m + len(P) is a positive multiple of x.
Steps:
1. Let j = (– m – 2) mod x.
2. Return P = 1 || 0(j) || 1

As an example, assume the message length is 135 bytes(not equal to block size = 136 bytes)
So, as per the above info
padded_msg = 135 bytes || 1F || 0's(135) || 80(in hex) = 272 bytes

Is the understanding correct ?
And if len = 134 bytes
padded_msg = 134 bytes || 1F || 80(in hex) [No zero's] = 136 bytes

And if len = 132 bytes
padded_msg = 132 bytes || 1F || 0's(2) || 80(in hex) [Two zero's] = 136 bytes

and if padding length = multiple of 136, no padding is needed.

When there's more than 2 bytes to pad:
0x1f || 0x00^* || 0x80

When there's only 2 bytes to pad:
0x1f || 0x80

When there's only 1 byte to pad:
0x1f xor 0x80

When it's exactly the block size, pad an entire extra block - i.e. more than 2 bytes.

when len==blocksize, extra block padded will be [0x1f || 0x00^*(134) || 0x80]. Correct ?

@Gappu Yes, that's correct assuming block size (a.k.a. sponge rate) is 136 octets.
